# Resize multiple photos in word document

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have searched and experimented with multiple answers to my question, but they don't seem to work.  I have a database that prints to word a photo and text for each record.  The information is presented in a table format, with the pic/image located in a row in the table.  The images are created and saved by multiple users and are not all the same size.  The database is resizing the images to a predetermined size that I do not want.  I want to macro to resize all the images to 3.5" in height.  I don't really care about the width, but want the aspect ratio to be locked.  I have found some answers, but the aspect ratio solution doesn't seem to work.  This component of the code ".LockAspectRatio = msoTrue" seems to be ignored when the macro is run.  As a result, the image gets distorted or stretched.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I'm currently using, but I've tried some others:

Sub ResizePhotos()
    Dim pic As InlineShape

```
For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With pic
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        If .Width > .Height Then ' horizontal
            .Height = InchesToPoints(3.5)
        Else  ' vertical
            .Width = InchesToPoints(5)
        End If
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: I'd suggest using Image Magick https://imagemagick.org/index.php to resize them all outside of VBA for best quality. As to your macro, we can't help you with it if you don't provide it; please click [edit] and paste the macro text into your question. Please don't use Add Comment for it has no formatting; please instead use [edit]. Editing tips are at http://superuser.com/editing-help#code

Comment: The comment has been edited.  Thank you for responding!

Comment: Just circling back.  Does anyone have a solution?